# Where to ask questions on prehistory?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

My favorite topic is prehistory like dinosaurs, early homo sapiens, sun, mars and so on. Which is the appropriate forum to ask such questions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, for dinosaurs and early homo sapiens, it looks like [Biology](https://biology.stackexchange.com/).

As for Earth, Mars, etc., it'll probably be [Physics](http://physics.stackexchange.com) or possibly [Space Exploration](https://space.stackexchange.com/).

I suppose things like tectonic plate theory would be okay for [Earth Sciences](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/).

Of course, there is also a [`prehistory`](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prehistory) tag at [History](https://history.stackexchange.com/)

As always, read the **Help Center** to see what's on-topic.

Comment: If dinosaurs can do math, [hsm.se] might handle it too ;))

Comment: @Ooker it's a shame the _History of Martian Dino-Science_ site never made it to the beta phase.